# Insert binary file with COPY in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have a Postgres database that I am populating with CSV files using [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-copy.html). Some tables have columns of type `bytea`, and in these CSV files it is specified the path to the binary file.
Given the table

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
( ID INTEGER,
  File BYTEA
);
```

I know I can insert binary files with

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1, pg_read_binary_file('/path/to/file'));
```

but, can I specify to do so with `COPY` reading the `/path/to/file` from the CSV files? Can you apply functions to `COPY` in Postgres? I know in MySQL you can do it using something like

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE /path/to/csv
INTO TABLE mytable
( ID,
  @File
)
SET File = LOAD_FILE(@File);
```

but I have to stick to Postgres and store the binary files in the database.

Comment: You need to pick a programming language and write a program replacing these paths by the contents of the files in hex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import your csv file into a temporary table without processing the filenames.

Then have a separate INSERT that calls `pg_read_binary_file`.